# When I use spring data to save an entity, the Repository returns a null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I've been working with Spring Data with the JavaConfig documentation I have set up a Spring JPA configuration, but when calling the save method in my repository a null pointer exception is thrown.

this is the github project : https://github.com/Ibrahimhizeoui/HRessources.git
My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee,Integer> 
{
}
```

My class :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date created_at;
private Date updated_at;
public Employee() {}
 }
//getters & setters
```

The class which uses my repo :

```
public class EmployeeDao {

@Autowired
private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

public void saveEmployee(Employee employee){
    employeeRepository.save(employee);

}}
```

And this is my Jpa Config :

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="dao")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfiguration {

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb =
new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
emfb.setPackagesToScan("model");
return emfb;
}

@Bean(name = "dataSource")
public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new 
DriverManagerDataSource();
    driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

driverManagerDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hressource");
    driverManagerDataSource.setUsername("root");
    driverManagerDataSource.setPassword("");
    return driverManagerDataSource;
}

@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new 
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.MYSQL);
    return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
}

 @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor 
  exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

 @Bean
 public BeanPostProcessor persistenceTranslation() {
 return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
 }}
```

I am fairly new to Spring Data, so I do think it's something within the configuration that I am missing. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at dao.EmployeeDao.saveEmployee(EmployeeDao.java:16)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

this is the github project : https://github.com/Ibrahimhizeoui/HRessources.git My repos

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling `saveEmployee` from your `Main.java` `main` method, then of course it won't work because you have no spring context created and hence your `EmployeeRepository` is not autowired and equals to `null`. You can launch your application using Spring Boot (for example):

```
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("model")
@EnableJpaRepositories("dao")
public class Main {

    /**
     * Run the application using Spring Boot and an embedded servlet engine.
     *
     * @param args program arguments - ignored.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

        EmployeeDao employeeDao = context.getBean("dao", EmployeeDao.class);

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setFirstName("ib");
        employeeDao.saveEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to add a @Component annotation to your DAO class:

```
@Component("dao")
public class EmployeeDao
```